# Spring-security: application shares web pages and REST API

Tags: javascript, spring-security

I am currently working on a Spring-MVC application which hosts my html web pages and also a (kind of) REST API.
The problem is depending what is accessing the application, an authentication failure should be handled differently:

- if the user accesses the pages with his browser, he must be redirected to the login page (302 which is managed by the browser)
- if it is a component inside a page (a jquery datatable in my case) which tries to load the next page of result through Ajax, I should receive a 401 status to allow me to interpret it in my JS and redirect to the login page.

But actually, the application always returns a 302 which is handled by the browser without giving a chance to my Javascript to handle it properly.

From my reading, I found that I have to define 2 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, I did it, one for the /api, and another for the web pages but it keeps sending the redirect 302 in both cases.

My API configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 5)
public class RestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf()
    .disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/**")
    .authenticated();

}
}
```

And the web config:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 10)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/action/**", "/login", "/css/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
}
...
}
```

Is someone able to help me to understand what is wrong?

I saw some solutions which read the content of Ajax response and redirect if there's some html inside, but I think that it should be handled properly on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be close. Remember that when you define a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, you need to say what kinds of authentication mechanisms you want to use:

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@Order(99)
public class RestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic(); // <-- use HTTP basic
    }
}
```

Also, note a subtle difference between `requestMatchers` and `authorizeRequests`. When you have different `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s, they get segmented by path using `requestMatchers`.

The meaning of the above snippet is "for requests that match /api/**, authenticate any request with HTTP basic."

For web security, we want to process "everything else", so we don't need a `requestMatchers()`. So, to do the same for your web security, you'd do:

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@Order(100)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/action/**", "/login", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
        // ...
        ;
    }
}
```

The meaning of the above snippet is "authenticate any request with Form login."

Finally, Spring Security will process `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s in ascending `@Order`. So, notice that the first one is "99" and the second one is "100". That means the `RestSecurityConfig` will be processed before the `WebSecurityConfig`. You can think of it like an if statement:

```java
if (request matches /api) {
   check the `RestSecurityConfig` configuration
} else {
   check the `WebSecurityConfig` configuration
}
```

Comment: For my understanding, the Basic authentication is not used as such, it's more like a trick to make the filter returns a 401 if no other filters accept the request, am I right? Because when I looked at the code, I thought that I had to add a user/password header but it is not the case , it is working like that.

Comment: Using `httpBasic` means that you are using `Authorization: Basic` for your API clients. Truthfully, `Authorization: Bearer` is becoming more common. You should specify the mechanism by which your REST API clients will prove who they are.

Answer (score 1):

You need custom rest authenticationentrypoint:

```
@Component
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
@Override
public void commence(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

    response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized" );
   }
}
```

also register it to httpsecurity in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation like:

```
@Autowired
RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler restAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
       http.
          ...
          .exceptionHandling()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
          .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin")
}
```

so you will handle 401 unauthorized in the front application.
Also no need for `.loginPage("/login")` as you have REST, otherwise you will be redirected and by above configuration you will not be redirected(302), instead it sends 401 to app running in your browser. In you front app you will post credentials to "/doLogin".

Comment: Maybe I was unclear but I need the redirection AND the 401, depending how the application is reached: the browser needs the 302, and the jquery components need the 401. Otherwise, I can separate my application, one for the web application and one for the API but it is not what I want to do.

Comment: I thought you had just rest API, I misunderstood question... then my logic can be applied to the earliest ordered filter chain with  `http.antMatcher("/restapi/**")` along with higher ordered filtechain working with 302 redirect